# I have strange behavior with .NET serial port class

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a couple of applications in VB 6.0 which i want to move to C#.NET so I was looking for serial communication example. So far so good.

There was a couple of examples on the Internet but none of them worked on my PC (Win7 64bit, VS2012, .NET 4.5) so i decided to try them on another PC. Here is where everything start look like The X Files...

The sample application I'm trying is [this one](https://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx)

First I've tried on a notebook with Win8 64bit now working at all.
Then I tried on a desktop pc with Win7 64bit 3.5 .NET not receiving only transmitting. I installed .NET 4.0 and it stopped working at all.

I tried on same model another desktop PC, Win7 32bit 3.5 NET.  It's working OK both receiving and transmitting. Installed .NET 4.0 and no receive no transmit. Uninstall .NET 4.0 still not working. Restore from restore poing before .NET 4.0 working again. After a couple of test stopped working no matter restore point or not.

I tried on another desktop pc with Win8 64bit worked ok, then installed .NET 4.5 stopped working at all. Tried on XP too 3.5 .NET working OK and .NET 4.0 OK. On all computers my old VB6.0 program is working OK no matter if .net example is working or not.

Can someone tell me what is going on? Also how to create program and give it to customer when it is so unstable?

I'm looking over the Internet for more than 3 days and nights and still haven't found somebody with problems like mine. Am I doing something wrong or just I'm missing something about the whole .NET thing ? I'll post more info about my tries if it's necessary!

Comment: Your computer still has RS-232 ports?!? Have you checked the cable, is it bad?

Comment: Any error messages when it stops working? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: I have additional pci card with rs232 port on my developer machine. I have change it with another model still the same. Other pc's have com port on motherboard. No errors no nothing... Just nothing... The cable, the port and everything else is ok as i said they are working with my old application written in VB6.0 on the same computers...

The devices i test with are proximity readers for access control connected through rs232<->rs485 converter, but i don't think that it can be this because they are working with older software !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found the problem... It's me ofcourse :) the strange behavior is result of not checking DTR check of the sample application. When DTR is checked it's working on my developer machine and on other machines too. This however does not answer why it's working on some machines and not on others without DTR checked. Also why it's working OK with Windows XP without DTR but the important thing is i have found how it should be to work correctly. Thanks to Alan & Ted for their time to post answers to me.

Comment: Serial port problems usually boil down to "your settings are incorrect" or a hardware problem (usually due to a USB serial port).